# Can someone explain why this doesn't work VS this

Tags: powershell

So I have revisited a profile script I was writing and I tried to do it from scratch with what I have learnt, however I got to the part where I search for a Regkey based on a username.

The -Like function worked but when i done -eq it didn't, what am I missing?

```
Get-ChildItem $keypath | Where-Object {
    (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath).ProfileImagePath -like "*${Username}*"
}
```

The above worked but I also expected the below to work as well.

```
Get-ChildItem $keypath | Where-Object {
    (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath).ProfileImagePath -eq"*${Username}*"
```

Also why wouldn't this work

```
Where-Object { $_.ProfileImagePath -eq "$Username" }
```

I don't understand what is wrong with the -eq

I will also point out the working code was supplied to me ages ago on here so it's still greatly appreciated.

Comment: `-eq` doesn't support wildcards.

Comment: Please consider [reading the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)

Comment: `Where-Object { $_.ProfileImagePath -eq "$Username" }` does not work because `ProfileImagePath` is not a property of a RegistryKey object, which is what you are returning with `Get-ChildItem $keypath` here. `ProfileImagePath` is instead a value of a key.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for highlighting that again, I shall keep that in mind when wanting a return from a wildcard.

Comment: @AdminOfThings So above my script I have:

`$Username = $env:USERNAME`

is that even being used in this script, or is the wild card whats being looked at?

Comment: @DanielJamesVersace - PLEASE read up on basic scripting. of COURSE your `$UserName` assignment is being used [if it is done before the `-like`]. the wild card chars are ONLY used _as wildcards_ when used with a WILDCARD operator ... and `-eq` is not a wildcard operator. when you use `*$UserName*` with `-eq` you are doing a literal `*AcutalUserNme*` comparison. the asterisks are just characters, not wildcards.